# Keras fit predictions in Callback

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to get the predictions inside the function `on_epoch_end` of keras' `Callback`.
At the moment, to get the predictions, I execute `self.model.predict` with `batch_size` of 2, but at the 3rd epochs I get this error:

> RuntimeError: Dst tensor is not initialized in Tensorflow

Reading on the web, I notice that this error appears when the GPU goes out of memory. In my case, reading the stack trace, this error is triggered by `self.model.predict` inside `on_epoch_end`, it says:

> File "mlp_keras.py", line 20, in on_epoch_end predictions =
>   self.model.predict(self.dataset)

This is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mlp_keras.py", line 150, in <module>
    callbacks=[KendallTauHistory(training_dataset, training_dataset_labels, groups_id_count)])
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 397, in fit
    prefix='val_')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 771, in on_epoch
    self.callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 302, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "mlp_keras.py", line 20, in on_epoch_end
    predictions = self.model.predict(self.dataset)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1013, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 498, in predict
    workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 426, in _model_iteration
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 706, in _process_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 357, in __init__
    dataset = self.slice_inputs(indices_dataset, inputs)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 383, in slice_inputs
    dataset_ops.DatasetV2.from_tensors(inputs).repeat()
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 566, in from_tensors
    return TensorDataset(tensors)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2765, in __init__
    element = structure.normalize_element(element)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/util/structure.py", line 113, in normalize_element
    ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="component_%d" % i))
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1314, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py", line 52, in _default_conversion_function
    return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 258, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 266, in _constant_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "/usr/home/studenti/sp171412/word_ordering/mlp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 96, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
RuntimeError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

My question is: is there a way to get the predictions without performing `predict` inside `on_epoch_end`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about performing predict outside of `on_epoch_end`?

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci where, exactly? I need to get the predictions of each epoch

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after seeing your last comment, what you could do:

```
epochs = 100
for epoch in range(epochs):
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_predict = model.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try. Is this methodology allocates less GPU?

Comment: I am not sure .

Comment: unfortunately, now the GPU goes out of memory at the ```model.predict()``` of the first epoch.

Comment: Maybe you could try splitting your dataset and make multiple predictions?

Comment: I'll try. Before I want to ensure that the problem is caused by the ```predict()```.